# how to find episode link among many episodes in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to write code with selenium python.
I work on site like https://www.thewatchcartoononline.tv/anime/south-park-season-1. As you can see this page is the page for the series with links to all the episode of the series.
I want to get the link of a given episode (the user chooses which one).

Important to note that not every series page has the same naming format for the episodes, some series has only "Episode 1" in the link text, others may have "South park season 1 episode 1" in the link, so I cant count on the naming format of the link's text.

this is the code I used to get the link to the episode (`episode_num` is given by the user)

```
episode_num = 1
chrome_driver = Chrome()
chrome_driver.get("https://www.thewatchcartoononline.tv/anime/south-park-season-1")
# This xpath takes you to the div of the episode list and then it search for a link which has a certain text in it
links = chrome_driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            f"//*[@id='sidebar_right3']//"
            f"a[contains(text(), 'Episode {episode_num}')]"
        )
```

However when I check `links` I see that there are more than one link. I get both episode 1 and episode 10 (since both of them contain the string "Episode 1")
Is there a way to get only the link I want? (maybe to make selenium take the link that doesn't have any digit after the text I want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Well, kind of ugly, but in Xpath 1.0 I think this is the best you can do.

```
links = chrome_driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//*[@id='sidebar_right3']//a[(contains(., 'Episode {episode_num} ')) or (substring(text(), string-length(text()) - string-length('Episode {episode_num}') +1) = 'Episode {episode_num}') or (contains(., 'Episode {episode_num}-')) ]")
```

Finds Episode 10-11 for `episode_num = 10` but not for `episode_num = 11`.

Checks for:

- is `Episode x` in the `text()`
- `text()` ends with `Episode x`
- is `Episode x-` in the `text()`

I was checking the urls of the episodes. Wouldn't be a better approach relying on the `@href` instead of the `text()`? This is a bit shorter:

```
links = chrome_driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//*[@id='sidebar_right3']//a[(contains(@href, 'episode-{episode_num}-')) or (substring(@href, string-length(@href) - string-length('episode-{episode_num}') +1) = 'episode-{episode_num}')]")
```

Checks for:

- is `episode-x-` in the url
- url ends with `episode-x`

Comment: I have tried that, but as I mentioned, you cant rely on this space. In some pages there is no space after the episode number, in some there is a '-' and therefore it is not a reliable method

Comment: Provide examples please (urls worth checking for examples).

Comment: https://www.thewatchcartoononline.tv/anime/avatar-the-last-airbender-book-3-fire. in this page every link ends with the episode number (except one time when there is a '-' after the episode number)

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: The first answer still rely on the format of the text, which would not work. There are many options in this site and I cant cover all of them. your second answer is more reliable, however it would only work for this site (other site which don't use this style of url will fail with this method). I give you the answer but if you have a way to check if the number match exactly please update your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try following `xpath`.Use last() option this should give count 1.

```
links = chrome_driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//*[@id='sidebar_right3']//a[contains(text(), 'Episode {episode_num}')])[last()]")
print(len(links))
```